# Can't run the urllib.request in Pycharm

Tags: python, request, pycharm, urllib

I use this code in Pycharm but got nothing to output in the console.

```
import  urllib.request as request
src="https://www.ntu.edu.tw/"
with request.urlopen(src) as response:
    data=response.read()
print(data)
```

But I  run this code on the cmd.
I can get the output of the source code of the website.

[image]

I wanna know how can I get the output in Pycharm.

Comment: Maybe indent line 4?

Comment: Open `Python Console` window from `view->Tool Window->Python Console`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). It is easier to handle and the documentation is very well.

You can use it like:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get(src)
print(resp.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

check your present working directory to make sure the file you are trying to run is in your work space.